# Recent search functionality

Tags: c#, .net, search, outlook

I am working on C#.Net windows application. Here i want to implement search functionality as like as Microsoft outlook 2007 instant search. This functionality have "Recent Searchs", i want to listout last 20 searchs. These 20 search items where i have to store(file/db) and how to bring .

Thanks

Comment: Is your question "how do I use a database in C#?"  It's a little unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last 20 Searches in the current run of the application? A List of strings (of size 20) can be good, keeping in mind managing their order.
Or create a database table of of the recent searches, making sure everytime you add an entry that it doesn't exceed 20, and delete the oldest row if it does to make space.